# UIDatePicker Background isn't changing

Tags: xcode, uidatepicker, uibackgroundcolor

I've been trying to change the background && text color for the UIDatePicker, I'm executing this code via ViewDidLoad. The text color changes, but the background color refuses to change. Instead when I run the app and the view loads for the first time, it doesn't change the color, but if I tap inside of the textfield then go to the previous screen then click on the textfield the background color changes like it's supposed to. This is my code for the viewdidload method below:

```
UIDatePicker *endTimeDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
endTimeDatePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255 
green:0/255 blue:0/255 alpha:0.8];
[endTimeDatePicker setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:@"textColor"];
[endTimeDatePicker setDate:startTime];
endTimeDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[endTimeDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateEndTime:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[promoEndTime setInputView:endTimeDatePicker];
```

I'm really at a loss, I also tried other variations to set the background color...

setbackground color, set tintcolor, uicolor black

still nothing, still the same result, any assistance would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally setting `backgroundColor` is all that's needed. If you had added the date picker in interface builder, it would work. I suspect that when you call `setInputView`, your `promoEndTime` is overriding that setting by changing it to something else.

You *might* get around that by setting the background color *after* calling `setInputView`. But you might find it better to change your strategy, because date pickers are notoriously resistant to UI changes. You're already on thin ice here with Apple, because the `textColor` setting is undocumented. Using undocumented API is a major risk of having Apple reject your app from the store. I agree that better appearance customization would be **extremely** nice here, but changing the text color is asking for trouble from Apple.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to just leave the picker the default grey with black text, which kind of takes away from the app because the UIPICKERVIEWS have black background with white text. So hopefully it isn't something that affects the users experience. Thanks for giving me the heads up on Apple policies, i'm definitely trying to keep everything within the lines of submission, i've never made an app this huge before, so i'm learning alot along the way.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for a way to change background color of calendar popup on new ios 14 uidatepicker compact style then this is what worked for me:

```
(UIVisualEffectView.classForCoder() as? UIAppearanceContainer.Type).map({ UIDatePicker.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [$0]).backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow })
```